# Code that displays date and time in javascript iterates to the next day at 5pm every day

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that I use to display the date and time on an html web page.

I've noticed that the date changes to the following day (ex. Oct 1 --> Oct 2) every day at 5pm. I want to make sure this date changes at 12am every day and not 5pm. I'm wondering where the error is in my code that causes this to occur.

**Here is the Javascript code I use:**

```
function GetClock(){
    var tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    var d=new Date();
    var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();


    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML=""+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+"";
}

function GetTime(city, offset){
    var tzOffset = -7;

    var d=new Date();
    var dx=d.toGMTString();
    dx=dx.substr(0, dx.length -3);
    d.setTime(Date.parse(dx))
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + tzOffset);

    var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),ap;
    if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
    else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
    else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
    else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

    if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=""+nhour+":"+nmin+ap+"";
}

window.onload=function(){
    GetTime();
    setInterval(GetTime,1000);
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a timezone offset of -7 in there. Change the value of `tzOffset` to 0 and it should be fine.